# Regex help in objective c

Tags: objective-c, regex

```
<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x100217890>{0, 4}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x100214700> test 0x1}
```

This is one element in the array which stores the result of a regular expression search.

I've got what I want: 'test'. I don't however want all the stuff around it ie

```
<NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x100217890>{0, 4}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x100214700> etc
```

I've got a feeling I'm going to have to send something to this element ie

[element stringValue];

but I need a little help discovering what that is..

My full code is below:

```
NSString *test = @"test 123 test";
NSRegularExpression* regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"test" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSArray* result = [regex matchesInString:test options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [test length])];
NSLog(@" %@", [result objectAtIndex:0]);
```

which puts out

```
 <NSSimpleRegularExpressionCheckingResult: 0x105b17890>{0, 4}{<NSRegularExpression: 0x105b14700> test 0x1}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[regex matchesInString...
```

gives you NSArray of NSTextCheckingResults.
Maybe you'd want to use firstMatchInSting:options:range:
It will give you NSTextCheckingResult, from which you can get range (NSRange) which you apply to your string with substringWithRange: method.

I hope you can understand. If not - I'll explain more carefully.
Nevertheless, read [NSRegularExpression reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSTextCheckingResult reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTextCheckingResult_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSTextCheckingResult)

Comment: Yes! Think this is it.. So basically, I'm using the regular expression to find the location of the substring I want in the string (ie the range) and then I can grab that range from the NSString? Does that sound like I have understood correctly?

Comment: @neutreno basically it's correct. Actual solution is bit more complicated, but if you look up references and some questions here on topic - you'll have no problem.

Comment: seems a pretty convoluted way of doing things. Much unlike php etc. which I am used to!

Comment: @neutreno it's all a matter of habit. At first I was horrified by Obj-C, but then it became pretty simple (until you get into CF)

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I'm making process. If I send 'regularExpression' to the element, it narrow the result down to

```
<NSRegularExpression: 0x106214700> test 0x1
```

I'm aware that this is the print-out of an object but I am still unsure how to isolate the text!

Comment: Okay.. it might be worth ignoring this question as I have simply got myself very confused.....